# Result query to attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm a beginner on JPA and I don't know pass result of a query to attribute entity.
Let me explain in one example:

I have an entity called Team, and another called Players:
The player is children of Team.

Class Team:

```
public class Team{
...

(relationship with Player has been hidden)
...

@Column(name = "AMOUNT_PLAYERS")
private Short amountPlayers;

@Column(name = "AMOUNT_FIRSTSTRING_PLAYERS")
private Short amountFirstStringPlayers;

@Column(name = "AMOUNT_SECONDSTRING_PLAYERS")
private Short amountSecondStringPlayers;

...

}
```

Class Player:

```
Public class Player{

...

@Column("STATUS_PLAYER")
private Short statusPlayer;
...

}
```

I have two questions about this.

1) In the `amountPlayers`, I want number total of player from this team;
In the  `amountFirstStringPlayers`, I want number total of players (first-string) with `statusPlayer` of `Player` equals 1;
And in the `amountSecondStringPlayers`, I want number total of players (second-string) with `statusPlayer` of `Player` equals 2; 
How I can get this values when I Find entity with JPA. 
Example:

```
SELECT team FROM Team team
```

When I execute this, I want `amountPlayers`, `amountFirstStringPlayers` and `amountSecondStringPlayers`.

2) Put the resultQuery in an attribute of an entity, on an entity is a good practice?

Comment: does select * from team return all these values from the database or you want to do some processing of data after retrival from database

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh for comment, I do it and I use second option and  work fine for me. But I'd like to know if there is a way to do this using the entity, and if it's a good practice . Just by knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hibernate formula which are very convenient for these cases where you dont really need to persist these computed datas.

ex :

```
@Formula("(select count(*) from Player p where p.team_id = id)")
private Short amountPlayers;

@Formula("(select count(*) from Player p where p.team_id = id and p.statusPLayer=1)")
private Short amountFirstStringPlayers;

@Formula("(select count(*) from Player p where p.team_id = id and p.statusPLayer=2)")
private Short amountSecondStringPlayers;
```

Formula accepts sql string as parameter and here in the example `id` is the `id` of the current entity. You must replace with your entity id name and column.

If you don't want to use Formula you can also compute these values in memory based on players relation in your team entity.

ex:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="team")
private List<Player> players; // Here your onetomany association

public short getAmountPlayers(){
return players!= null ? players.size() : 0;
}
```